# Where to physically write commands for input redirection in C?

Tags: c

This might sound like a retarded question but I am just learning C and all the websites I looked at this showed you the command to do it (project < somefile.txt) but not where to do it. Does it go in my project somewhere or command prompt? And if it is command prompt how do I get to where I need to enter it?

Comment: This kind of command goes on the command-prompt when you run your program.

Comment: That's a command... for the command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes on your command prompt. You first need to cd into location where your compiled binaries are. That command basically says "run project and feed contents of somefile.txt into it"

If you're on Windows hit Win+R and run cmd. On UNIX you should find [terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_emulator) app somewhere in your menu.

Answer (score 0):

Write your C code to use the built in `FILE` pointers defined in `stdio.h`. Read from `STDIN` and write to `STDOUT`.  When you run your command like this: `project < somefile.txt`, the shell will open `somefile.txt` as `STDIN` before your program runs.